# Stripe dynamic additional costs to subscription

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I have a graduated pricing model on Stripe. It has a flat fee of $100 up to 1000 items (those are conversation queries used by customer). After 1000 queries, each one should be charged $0.05. These queries are dynamic i.e. they vary from month to month. I set up the subscription in the way that it takes the flat fee and deducts just that fee at the end of each month.

How can I add these dynamic additional charges to the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use here is [Metered Billing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing) with [tiered pricing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/tiers).